# how to keep count of each items in list - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, list, algorithm

i was trying to keep count of each item in list in python and want to convert it into key-value pairs like json so i can able to iterate over it to present it on frontend using django.

```
list = ["a" , "a", "c",  "b", "c", "d"]
```

here same i want this list into key value pairs with counting of each item in list

```
list = [{ "name":"a" , "count":2 } , { "name":"c" , "count":2 , ......}]
```

Comment: [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: I second `collections.Counter`. You can get the desired output like this `[{"name": name, "count": count} for name, count in Counter(list).items()]`. Also avoid using `list` as a name for a variable.

Comment: it would be great if you write it down for me

Comment: isn't that what I just did?

Answer (score 3):

Use a set to count the number of each element in the list

```
l = ["a" , "a", "c",  "b", "c", "d"]
d = {val: l.count(val) for val in set(l)}
```

this will give you :

```
{'c': 2, 'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1}
```

If you want to format the dict as you wrote it in your message (even though it's really inefficient), you can write it like that :

```
d = [{'name': val, 'count': l.count(val)} for val in set(l)}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data = ["a" , "a", "c",  "b", "c", "d"]
count_list=[{"name":d,"count": data.count(d)} for d in set(data)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to do this:

```
def dict_count(list):
    dict_tot = {}
    for i in liste:
        dict_tot[i] = liste.count(i)
    print(dict_tot)
```